# Inequality for product of two nonnegative number

Tags: inequality

If $x,y\geq0$ and $p,q$ are positive numbers satisfying $1/p+1/q=1$, then for any $A>0$, 
$$xy\leq \frac{x^p}{Ap}+\frac{Ay^q}{q}.$$
 How to prove the above inequality? This may have some connections with Young's inequality. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is not $A^p$ and $A^q$ that appears on the right hand side?

Comment: If $A^p$  and $A^q$ appears on the right hand side, it becomes Young's inequality. It may have some connections with Young's inequality, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Is really $A$ in the denominator in the 1st term? If it is in the numerator, as in the 2nd term, the inequality follows trivially by the weighted AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Yes, $A$ is in the denominator in the 1st term. This is what I saw in a PhD dissertation and there is no proof.

Comment: Then AM-GM inequality gives us the $xyA^{1/q-1/p}$ estimate. Maybe it is not optimal. The inequality should hold. For $p=q=2$ my argument works excellently. Of course, this is not the proof in general. :)

Answer (score 1):

The inequality can only hold for $A=1$, which is Young's inequality.

Consider $0<\alpha<1$ and set 
$$x=\alpha\qquad y=\frac1\alpha.$$
If the inequality were true, then 
$$
1\le \frac{\alpha^p}{Ap} + \frac{A}{\alpha^q q}.$$
Letting $p\to\infty, q\to 1$, we obtain $A\ge \alpha$. Now set 
$$x=\frac1\alpha\qquad y=\alpha.$$
This yields 
$$1\le \frac{1}{\alpha^p p A} + \frac{A \alpha^q}{q}.$$
Letting now $p\to1$ and $q\to\infty$ we obtain $A\le\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

We conclude that 
$$\alpha\le A \le \frac{1}{\alpha}, $$ 
and since $0<\alpha<1$ was arbitrary, this implies $A=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the proof!

Comment: @SHAN: There's probably a typo in the dissertation. The correct inequality is Young's, that is, replace $A$ with $A^p$ and $A^q$ in the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.